# Solving a Nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Does this problem have a unique solution in $[t_0,t_1]$?

$$ \ddot x(t)=\alpha(1-t)\cos(x(t))$$ 
$$x(t_0)=0$$
$$ \dot x(t_1)=0$$

Thanks!

Comment: Is this intended to be a BVP rather than an IVP?

Comment: Maple can solve the equation without the conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), or the [Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cauchy-Lipschitz_theorem). To see this, write your second order ODE as a two-dimensional system of first order ODE's:
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} t} &= y(t),\\
 \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} t} &= (1-t) \cos(x(t)).
\end{align}
You can now show that the function
\begin{equation}
f : (t_0,t_1) \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2,\quad f(t;x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} y \\ (1-t) \cos(x) \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is Lipschitz continuous (on a certain set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$), by showing that there exists a constant $L$ such that
\begin{equation}
 \|f(t;x,y) - f(t;\hat{x},\hat{y})\| \leq L \left\| \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}\hat{x}\\ \hat{y} \end{pmatrix} \right\|
\end{equation}
for all $t \in (t_0,t_1)$ and all $(x,y),(\hat{x},\hat{y}) \in U$.

**EDIT**: The above is true for initial value problems. In your case, the question at hand is really one of existence. In other words: given $t_0$, $t_1$, does there exist $y_0,x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the orbit in the above ODE system associated to the initial condition $(x(t_0),y(t_0)) = (0,y_0)$ obeys $(x(t_1),y(t_1)) = (x_1,0)$? This question is a lot harder to answer.

A clue to the answer can be found in the observation that we can bound the right hand side of the original ODE:
\begin{equation}
 \left| \alpha (1-t) \cos x \right| \leq |\alpha(1-t)|.
\end{equation}
For second order ODE's with such a property, existence of a boundary value problem such as the one you described can be found in Theorem 2.1 and Corollary 2.2 in

Lloyd K Jackson, *Subfunctions and second-order ordinary differential inequalities*, Advances in Mathematics 2(3) (1968), pp 307-363 [[DOI]](http://Subfunctions%20and%20second-order%20ordinary%20differential%20inequalities).

Comment: Yes, but isn't this correct only for IVPs?

Comment: True, so to re-interpret your question: does there exist an initial condition $x'(t_0) = y_0$ such that the second coordinate of the associated solution to the ODE system obeys $y(t_1) = 0$ ? (I assume $t_0$ and $t_1$ are given.) It's not so much a question of uniqueness then, but whether such a solution exists at all -- and that's a lot harder to answer. But if such a solution exists, it is unique.

Comment: Found a literature reference chasing an idea using differential inequalities; updated my answer. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes, this is called shooting and I am familiar with it as a numerical method. But can you provide a reference to the theorem concerning your last statement? Thank you.

Comment: To my knowledge, shooting is something different, but that doesn't really matter at this point. The reference could, and can still be found in my answer, last line. You might have missed the fact that I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes I noticed it after I wrote. Thanks.